# Автоматический самозапуск скрипта повторно

Tags: php

Пишу бота для телеграм, который по запросу должен скачивать файл со стороннего сайта и отправлять его мне. Иногда случается, что сайт оказывается недоступен и скрипт просто безрезультатно умирает. Соответственно, мне нужно, чтобы в этот момент скрипт отправил сообщение о неудаче и через пару минут перезапустился бы сам. Подскажите, как корректно реализовать автозапуск php скрипта (на Debian) через какое-то время, если предыдущий его вызов не завершился ожидаемым результатом? Я читал про Cron, но не понял, подходящий ли это инструмент

Answer (score 1):

Думаю сообщения о неудаче стоит добавлять в базу данных, а другой скрипт запускается по крону каждые (1-3-5-10-etc) минут и пробует получить результаты

Comment: да, я пришел примерно к такому же выводу, прежде чем обратиться сюда. Меня смутило, что для достижения приемлемых таймингов возврата результата придется долбить бд (часто без повода) каждые пару секунд

Comment: Можно хранить в БД данные и в файле флаг true/false, если в файле true значит все операции успешны и подключатся к БД не требуется, это сократит кол-во подключений